# 19.10 + Nomachine nxclient_3.5.0-7_amd64.deb

Tags: nomachine

so i'm a long time user of nomachine products.
Lately i was (still am) happily using nxclient 3.5 on an ubuntu 18.04 to connect to a nomachine workstation 6.4 server (evaluation version).

Things are working great, minus the required replacement of the included libz.so.1.2.3 that apparently fails in 18.04 and has to be overwritten with the system version.

However, doing the same on a ubuntu 19.10 (and 20.04) doesn't work anymore, and the client appears to hang during connection with this sshlog:

```
NX> 203 NXSSH running with pid: 7507
NX> 285 Enabling check on switch command
NX> 285 Enabling skip of SSH config files
NX> 285 Setting the preferred NX options
NX> 200 Connected to address: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port: xxxx
NX> 202 Authenticating user: nx
NX> 208 Using auth method: publickey
HELLO NXSERVER - Version 6.4.6 - NoMachine Workstation Evaluation
NX> 105 NX> 280 Exiting on signal: 15
```

to compare with the same package ran on 18.04, here's the sshlog from the other machine:

```
NX> 203 NXSSH running with pid: 4430
NX> 285 Enabling check on switch command
NX> 285 Enabling skip of SSH config files
NX> 285 Setting the preferred NX options
NX> 200 Connected to address: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port: xxxx
NX> 202 Authenticating user: nx
NX> 208 Using auth method: publickey
/usr/bin/xauth:  file /var/NX/nx/.Xauthority does not exist
HELLO NXSERVER - Version 6.4.6 - NoMachine Workstation Evaluation
NX> 105 Hello NXCLIENT - Version 3.5.0
NX> 134 Accepted protocol: 3.5.0
NX> 105 Set shell_mode: shell
NX> 105 Set auth_mode: password
NX> 105 Login 
NX> 101 User: <myuser>
NX> 102 Password: *********
NX> 103 Hello on board <myuser>.
NX> 105 Listsession --user="<myuser>" --status="suspended\054running" --geometry="1504x1000x24+render" --type="unix-application" 
NX> 127 Session list of user '<myuser>': 

Display Type                  Session ID                       Services Dept Screensize     Status      Session name                                                 Username                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
------- --------------------- -------------------------------- -------- ---- -------------- ----------- ------------------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

NX> 148 Server capacity: not reached for user: <myuser>
NX> 105 Start session with: --virtualdesktop="1" --application="startkde" --link="modem" --backingstore="1" --encryption="1" --cache="128M" --images="64M" --shmem="1" --shpix="1" --strict="0" --composite="1" --media="0" --imagecompressionmethod="3" --imagecompressionlevel="-1" --render="1" --session="nuc" --type="unix-application" --geometry="1024x768+240+101" --client="linux" --keyboard="pc101\057no" --screeninfo="1024x768x24+render" 
NX> 754 Selected node: localhost:4000
NX> 700 Session id: nuc3815-1001-6FE473B727960E71CAA298DAD537043D
NX> 705 Session display: 1001
NX> 701 Proxy cookie: 51BAA31D0AD12005261DA424BF1F5A96
NX> 702 Proxy IP: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
NX> 706 Agent cookie: 51BAA31D0AD12005261DA424BF1F5A96
NX> 704 Session cache: unix-application
NX> 722 UDP port: 5001
NX> 728 Session caption: NX - <myuser>@nuc3815:1001 - nuc
NX> 707 SSL tunneling: 1
NX> 708 Subscription: LWEN/None
NX> 710 Session status: running
NX> 105 Bye 
NX> 999 Bye.
NX> 285 Identified internal connection
NX> 285 Using default mode encrypted
NX> 285 Identified options: nx/nx,options=/home/<myuser>/.nx/S-nuc3815-1001-6FE473B727960E71CAA298DAD537043D/options:1001
NX> 280 Proxy opened with local: 11 remote: 12
NX> 285 Switching descriptors: 4 and: 5 to: 11

NX> 287 Redirected I/O to channel descriptors
NX> 280 Proxy in: 4 out: 5 transport in: 12 out: 12
NX> 280 Exiting on signal: 15
```

I don't fully understand what could be the reason for nxssh hanging after the server has replied, since the installed package and binaries are the same.. Any suggestions?

ps: the reason i'm asking about nxclient 3.5 is because i already tried to use the latest client, but it somehow sucks much harder when using the "light" protocol (= old nx protocol) compared to the 3.5 client, and that's why i'd like to stick to it.

*edit*: the full runlog:

```
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Setting environment variable 'NX_SYSTEM' to '/usr/NX'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Setting environment variable 'NX_ROOT' to '/home/<myuser>/.nx'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Setting environment variable 'NX_HOME' to '/home/<myuser>'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Starting font debug
Fixed font was set to: 'Fixed' size: '7'
And the result is: 'Fixed [Misc]'
Not using default system font
Trying preset families
Found family 'DejaVu Sans'
Found size '9'
Font was set to: 'DejaVu Sans'
And the result is: 'DejaVu Sans'
End of font debug


[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Starting NX Client version 3.5.0-7
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: qtrc: useXft read=1 value=1
qtrc: useXft is set to true
qtrc: enableXft read=1 value=1
qtrc: enableXft is set to true

[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Initializing the login dialog.
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Config File Name set to: '/home/<myuser>/.nx/config/nxclient.cfg'.
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: System NX dir set to: '/usr/NX'.
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Personal NX dir set to: '/home/<myuser>/.nx'.
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: creating SessionSettings=''
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: LoginDialog::loadConfigFiles - number of entries in config dir: 5
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: ComboSession::insertSession: 'nuc' -> '/home/<myuser>/.nx/config/nuc.nxs'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: ComboSession::setCurrentSession: 'nuc'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: SessionSettings::loadFromFile('/home/<myuser>/.nx/config/nuc.nxs')
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: ComboSession::insertSession: 'rivendell' -> '/home/<myuser>/.nx/config/rivendell.nxs'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: ComboSession::setCurrentSession: 'rivendell'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: SessionSettings::loadFromFile('/home/<myuser>/.nx/config/rivendell.nxs')
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Utility::getPreferencesFile: 'nxclient' -> '/home/<myuser>/.nx/config/nxclient.cfg'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: ComboSession::setCurrentSession: 'nuc'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: SessionSettings::loadFromFile('/home/<myuser>/.nx/config/nuc.nxs')
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: LoginDialog: slotChangeSession [nuc]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: LoginDialog: loadUserAndPassword
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: LoginDialog: loadUserAndPassword
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Settings::flush
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Settings::flush
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: ComboSession::setCurrentSession: 'nuc'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: SessionSettings::loadFromFile('/home/<myuser>/.nx/config/nuc.nxs')
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: LoginDialog: slotChangeSession [nuc]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: LoginDialog: loadUserAndPassword
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: LoginDialog: loadUserAndPassword
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Settings::flush
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Settings::flush
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: LoginDialog: loadUserAndPassword
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Setting environment variable 'NX_HOME' to '/home/<myuser>'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Setting environment variable 'NX_ROOT' to '/home/<myuser>/.nx'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Setting environment variable 'NX_SYSTEM' to '/usr/NX'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Setting environment variable 'NX_CLIENT' to '/usr/NX/bin/nxclient'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Trying the XAUTHORITY environment variable with value [/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority].
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Utility::getXAuthorityFilePath: /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Setting environment variable 'XAUTHORITY' to '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Setting environment variable 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' to '/usr/NX/lib'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Setting environment variable 'HOME' to '/home/<myuser>'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Setting environment variable 'PATH' to '/usr/lib/ccache/:/home/<myuser>/bin:/home/<myuser>/.local/bin:/home/<myuser>/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/NX/bin:/usr/X/bin'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Setting environment variable 'NX_TEMP' to '/tmp'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Setting environment variable 'TEMP' to '/tmp'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: Setting environment variable 'NX_VERSION' to '3.5.0'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:05 2020]: NXService::run: params [--cleanup]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: LoginDialog: login setupGui 1
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Setting environment variable 'NX_HOME' to '/home/<myuser>'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Setting environment variable 'NX_ROOT' to '/home/<myuser>/.nx'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Setting environment variable 'NX_SYSTEM' to '/usr/NX'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Setting environment variable 'NX_CLIENT' to '/usr/NX/bin/nxclient'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Trying the XAUTHORITY environment variable with value [/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority].
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Utility::getXAuthorityFilePath: /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Setting environment variable 'XAUTHORITY' to '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Setting environment variable 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' to '/usr/NX/lib'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Setting environment variable 'HOME' to '/home/<myuser>'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Setting environment variable 'PATH' to '/usr/lib/ccache/:/home/<myuser>/bin:/home/<myuser>/.local/bin:/home/<myuser>/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/NX/bin:/usr/X/bin:/usr/NX/bin:/usr/X/bin'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Setting environment variable 'NX_TEMP' to '/tmp'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Setting environment variable 'NX_VERSION' to '3.5.0'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Trying to write the ssh key into [/home/<myuser>/.nx/temp/7500/keylog]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: SSH key file path [/home/<myuser>/.nx/temp/7500/keylog]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Running nxssh protocol with version [3.5.0]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: LoginDialog: startProgressTimer
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: LoginDialog::ShowConnectionStatus code=[240] str=[Setting up the environment] error=[0]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: ProgressDialog::printNxStatus: [Setting up the environment]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: LoginDialog: startProgressTimer
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Showing progress dialog: Setting up the environment
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Going to get the X authorization cookie on display.
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Trying the XAUTHORITY environment variable with value [/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority].
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Running command [xauth -f /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority nextract - :0 | cut -f 9 -d ' ' 1>"/home/<myuser>/.nx/temp/7500/authlog" 2>/dev/null].
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Command run.
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Got or created the X authorization cookie.
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Setting environment variable 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' to ''
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Setting environment variable 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' to '/usr/NX/lib'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: LoginDialog::ShowConnectionStatus code=[241] str=[Connecting to <myserverdomain>] error=[0]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: ProgressDialog::printNxStatus: [Connecting to <myserverdomain>]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: LoginDialog::connectHost() nxsshline=/usr/NX/bin/nxssh -nx -p xxxx -i /home/<myuser>/.nx/temp/7500/keylog nx@<myserverdomain> -x -2 -4 -o RhostsAuthentication no -o PasswordAuthentication no -o RSAAuthentication no -o RhostsRSAAuthentication no -o PubkeyAuthentication yes -B -E
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Using NX_STDIN flag redirection for [nxssh] process
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Using NX_STDOUT flag redirection for [nxssh] process
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Using NX_STDERR flag redirection for [nxssh] process
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: SpawnProcess method has returned [1]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Process [nxssh] running with pid [7507]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Received line from nxssh process [NX> 203 NXSSH running with pid: 7507] with code [203]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Received code[203]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: NXProtocol: trying to read ssh pid from '7507' - read '7507'
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Received line from nxssh process [NX> 285 Enabling check on switch command] with code [285]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Received code[285]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Received line from nxssh process [NX> 285 Enabling skip of SSH config files] with code [285]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Received code[285]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Received line from nxssh process [NX> 285 Setting the preferred NX options] with code [285]
[Mon Feb 24 16:30:10 2020]: Received code[285]
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: StopConnection called
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: nxssh closing
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: StopConnection called
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: StopConnection called
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: nxssh closing
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: StopConnection called
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: printFatalError [Connection timeout]
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: KillAllComponents 0x1be2e60
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: LoginDialog: stopAllTimers
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: LoginDialog: stopProgressTimer
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: LoginDialog::killAllComponents() stopping NXProtoSSH
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: StopConnection called
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: nxssh closing
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: StopConnection called
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: NXProcessUnix::StopProcess process [nxssh] with pid [7507]
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: end of killAllComponents
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: LoginDialog::ShowConnectionStatus code=[268] str=[Connection timeout] error=[1]
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: ProgressDialog::printNxStatus: [Connection timeout]
[Mon Feb 24 16:31:10 2020]: Logfile path [/home/<myuser>/.nx/temp/7500/sshlog] exists.
[Mon Feb 24 16:32:01 2020]: LoginDialog::ShowConnectionStatus code=[251] str=[Disconnecting...] error=[0]
[Mon Feb 24 16:32:01 2020]: ProgressDialog::printNxStatus: [Disconnecting...]
[Mon Feb 24 16:32:01 2020]: KillAllComponents 0x1be2e60
[Mon Feb 24 16:32:01 2020]: LoginDialog: stopAllTimers
[Mon Feb 24 16:32:01 2020]: LoginDialog: stopProgressTimer
[Mon Feb 24 16:32:01 2020]: LoginDialog::killAllComponents() stopping NXProtoSSH
[Mon Feb 24 16:32:01 2020]: StopConnection called
[Mon Feb 24 16:32:01 2020]: nxssh closing
[Mon Feb 24 16:32:01 2020]: StopConnection called
[Mon Feb 24 16:32:01 2020]: NXProcessUnix::StopProcess process [nxssh] with pid [7507]
[Mon Feb 24 16:32:01 2020]: end of killAllComponents
```

and the runlog from the 18.04 installation (IP is different in this specific run, but it's the same machine. Have working runlogs also for remote connections), at http://paste.debian.net/hidden/7b6fcd46/ (due to message limits here on SE)

Comment: You need to show the full connection log.  Before that a tip: make sure `/usr/NX/bin/nxloadconfig` has the correct command to create hashes. Probably needs to be `md5sum` and not `openssl`.

Comment: thanks, i added the full logs. If it helps i can also add the logs from the machine (18.04) fro which things work fine

Comment: so, i seem not to have any nxloadconfig in that directory.
The content of /usr/NX/bin is: nxclient   nxesd      nxkill     nxprint    nxservice  nxssh

Comment: weird I'd expected a clear error notice in the log :P But these are just regular log entries. Oh and your config is set to "'/home/<myuser>/.nx/config/nxclient.cfg'." (2nd line ;) )

Comment: yes, well, i anonymized the log using <myuser> etc.

Comment: Would it be possible to create an appimage on 18.04 with *all* the dependencies, and run it on a 20.04?

Comment: In the end the only solution i found was via virtualbox.
Very sad scenario in  the linux landscape. And it does not look like it's going to improve.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem has occurred to me when I upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 some days ago.
After long search on WEB I found there is a Remmina NX plugin, you can install it through apt.

It works well, also I can hear sounds from server.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: And where is the plug-in?

Comment: does it work with the "Lite" protocol? i'm using nxserver only for that, no need for another h264 streamer otherwise. And iirc remmina supports the new protocol?

Comment: @Codito ergo sum: from a shell you can simply `sudo apt install remmina-plugin-nx` @PA_: what do you mean by "Lite" protocol? On the [Remmina](https://remmina.org/remmina-features/#nx-plugin-features) site you can find its features.